# New to VSCode, Python - some env questions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I went through a few articles about how to setup VSCode to work with python for the first time, and I'm very confused.
To me, VSCode seems messy - so many json settings which I manually need to configure...

Anyway, I now have 3 ways of running my python script:

1. F5, which runs via the terminal
2. Run (Ctrl+Shift+D), via Watson
3. Run via Code Runner

I don't understand the differences between the different methods of running my script.
Can someone please give me a short intro?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Terminal:

Terminal is fast and efficient to use. It also provides detailed information about the errors in your programs. And it is widely used buy a lot of Python programmers.

## Watson:

It provides developer tools for more advanced users. You can get more information about that from [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-ibm-dev-tools-for-vscode). Not recommended for a beginner.

## Code Runner:

Code runner is also used to see the the results of the programs but it is read only, and there can be some problems with that. As an example if you are building an application that takes the input from the user in Python, you can't do that via code runner.

## So which one is the best?

I would recommend using the Terminal (F5), because it is good for small programs, you get detailed information about your apps, the problems with your apps and some other options too. It is also fast and easy to use for a beginner.

> Hope it's clear now.